# Checking type resolution compltetly at runtime

Tags: typescript, compile-time

I'm writing some tests that checks that library I'm contributing to is working in intended way. For example I want to check if correct types get inferred for right expressions and so on.

For example we want to check this interface:

```js
interface Artifacts {
    require(name: String): any;
    require(name: "number"): number;
}
```

The problem is I couldn't figure out how to make it compile-time only thing. The best I could get was

```js
declare const dummyArtifacts: Artifacts;

export function test() {
  const numb = dummyArtifacts.require("number");
  const unknwn = dummyArtifacts.require("unknown");

  assert<Equals<number, typeof numb>>(true);
  assert<Equals<any, typeof unknwn>>(true);
}
```

Which produces unwanted nonempty output:

```js
export function test() {
    const numb = dummyArtifacts.require("number");
    const unknwn = dummyArtifacts.require("unknown");
    assert(true);
    assert(true);
}
```

Is there any way to make it working without emitting any JS at all (without cheating with --no-emit of course)? I found that I can get overloads via `Artifacts['require']` but I didn't invent any way to use them in any beneficial way.

I published a [small demo on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAeAGgGigTQD4oBeKACgwBVDyBKU4qqCAD2AgDsATNKLKAH4oARigAuKACYGbDjz7VaDEkxbsuvAgCgoQ0bonTDw4ACcEEQ5IBmqNBADc27dwgBjFEjPQbCTu7AAJYA9pxQSGgOZsAYAIK0SJJxdJIAbiFB3M7aQZwcZnbu0HExQUXAfADehno+iEE+5JxIALYQkgDK5nkA5qkRnCDOenUQDU0t7ZIARJwIrQBGEGYzA-NLK84Avi5unt7Q7mFowFDcC60gpcEVaMlldzlsYCExUH4BwWFQHKf0UBqemOnFOUA2i1I50u10eSECaAAdPUEI0IOQ5gtlqs6CMoCCwf4ANacADu4TIF1aVxu5XhlWR41RTRmxM4IXJaxyeki0Vi8GQ6AwEJWeFAkBCNnBWMItHMllxhl5K35iHsGCQQzF4AgkqgbPJsvI8ogiu2QA) with necessary boilerplate code

Comment: So you want to run run-time tests to check types that are not available at run-time? I am not sure why the Typescript compiler would not work for this use-case? If the wrong types gets inferred the consumer would not accept the type right?

Do you have to work with any? Because any gets a free-pass for all type checks

Comment: Checkout this example, the typescript check fails when the wrong type is inferred: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJTMeCwGdkDeAUMqclBAI4CuwFAFCHALYQBcyAymFKAOYBKDrh78A3CTIUadCIxbtkAIhDVmAI2hKhyVRugSAvkSIIA9iBHJmATwAyZvsATIAvMnoA3OABtqivU0oATcAPmRvPxQAamQARgkiCAAPAAczDGQYahAcYAtkSBF6EOJSc0swZAATNVt0TGw8N0JDZDh8BqxEPETyiytAltrmeoxunFwAOmlaBhU1IO0JfsrkHIBrEAB3EGG6my6m6dnZeiVNkDNd5ZNJWwcnBEZFgRXre0dnekvdt6JjEA

Comment: Just the opposite: I only want to check type inference so I don't need any runtime code at all. But it gets emitted and I didn't figure out any way to avoid it.

Comment: Just to be sure, JavaScript has no support for method overloading, your implementation would be a single method for all "Method" overloads you provide.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Software tests (by definition) occur as a result of some runtime operation. The feedback you see in your IDE (or the diagnostic messages in your console) are the result of TypeScript executing runtime code which parses your source files, converts to AST, validates the syntax, collects diagnostics, and emits any violations (that is an overly simplified description). How, exactly, do you plan to enforce a pass/fail condition in such a "type inference test"? (e.g. an exit code from a binary in a CLI process?) Also, what's wrong with emitting a test file?

Comment: @jsejcksn no they don't. I know I could do it in Flow but I wonder if it's possible in TS as well

Comment: @MaartenDev it shouldn't exist in JS at all. all I check is my inerfaces gets inferred correctly. Since interfaces do not exist in JS they shouldn't get into there